# WSL Error-Processing fstab with mount -a failed

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to utilize Docker. I also installed Ubuntu Linux in WSL. This is my WSL list:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl -l

Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
docker-desktop
Ubuntu-22.04
```

For configuring my Docker volumes , I wanted to run some Linux commands in the `docker-desktop-data` distro, but I got this error when trying to access the shell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl
Processing fstab with mount -a failed. 
<3>WSL (56) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:358: getpwuid(0) failed 2  
<3>WSL (56) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:362: getpwuid(0) failed 2
<3>WSL (56) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /bin/sh failed 2
<3>WSL (56) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
```

My Docker daemon and Ubuntu work fine, but I don't know how to run a command in any WSL distro.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't try the answer that you accepted originally, since it would have caused your Docker Desktop data to be deleted unrecoverably.  That answer was generated by ChatGPT and was just wrong in multiple ways.  I'd recommend waiting until you validate an answer in the future before upvoting or accepting.  But again, I'm hopeful that in this case you *didn't* try it, for your sake.  I'll try to post an answer in a bit.  Hopefully it will even be correct, but at least it will have been validated by a real person ;-)

Comment: because I said this "My Docker daemon and Ubuntu work fine, but I don't know how to run a command in any WSL distro", so somehow his answer was correct . I tried to unregister "docker-desktop-data" and tried to restart the docker service to make it regenerate docker-desktop-data distro. My problem remained, but I concluded this behavior is of the docker desktop.

Comment: your answer is a complete one, and there is no argue about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you can't access `docker-desktop-data` is simple -- You aren't supposed to!  There's no shell or executable inside it that can be launched, so WSL has nothing to actually *run* when you ask it to start the "distribution".

Both `docker-desktop` and `docker-desktop-data` are distributions that are *managed by* Docker Desktop and aren't meant to be used by end-users.  There's even [a proposal in the WSL Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8727) to have a way for these to be hidden from users by default.

I recommend that you return things to their "normal" state with:

```
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04
```

- `docker-desktop-data` is used simply as *storage* for Docker.  This is where your Docker volumes, images, and containers are stored.  Docker managed this for you.  If you feel you need to be doing something with that data that the `docker` commands can't handle, then I recommend you ask a separate question about *that* (and see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).
- `docker-desktop` contains a distribution with all of the Docker executables and sockets.  These are then linked into your other distributions (e.g. Ubuntu) so that you can run the `docker` commands there (as well as from PowerShell and CMD).  While you *can* enter this distribution, there's really no reason to.  Keep in mind that any changes that you make to this distribution:

  - Can potentially break Docker Desktop features
  - Will be reset, at a minimum, when Docker Desktop is upgraded, since a new `docker-desktop` distribution will be installed over the old one.

And while it's not recommended (since you can easily break things), you *can* at least *see* the contents of `docker-desktop-data` as they are mounted into the `docker-desktop` distribution:

```
wsl ~ -d docker-desktop

cd /mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-data
find
```

Answer (score 5):

this command works for me

```
wsl --set-default docker-desktop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).